# Detached head in gitlab ci pipeline - how to push correctly

Tags: git, gitlab-ci

I got some problems with a detached head for my repository in a CI pipeline. In the build stage of the pipeline I am running a script, which changes a specific file. After changing this file get pushed to the repository.

```
before_script:
  - git config --global user.name "Bot"
  - git config --global user.email "ci@domain.com"
  - git status
script:
  - npx ts-node ./generate.ts
  - git push "https://git:${GIT_PUSH_TOKEN}@${CI_REPOSITORY_URL#*@}" "HEAD:main"
  - git status
```

Running the script give me the output

```
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/fKSu5-y_/0/project/.git/
Created fresh repository.
Checking out 9b4a88be as main...

$ git status
HEAD detached at 9b4a88be

$ git push "https://git:${GIT_PUSH_TOKEN}@${CI_REPOSITORY_URL#*@}" "HEAD:main"
To https://gitlab.domain.com/project.git
9b4a88b..98be83e  HEAD -> main

$ git status
HEAD detached from 9b4a88b
```

I do not understand why the first `git status` in the before_script already gives me a detached head.

I think the pipeline creates a detached repository by initial fetching. So the question is how to handle my push in a correct way.
In my release stage I'm running `semantic-release` which fails because of detached head if I do the previous push. If I disable the push, semantic release is working as expected. But of course I need the push. I do not see, what I am doing wrong.

---

*Update*

Adding `git checkout main` in the before_script give me for the first `git status` the expected result. But after the push command I still have the detached head - which I do not understand.

```
$ git checkout main
Branch 'main' set up to track remote branch 'main' from 'origin'.
Switched to a new branch 'main'

$ git status
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

$ git push "https://git:${GIT_PUSH_TOKEN}@${CI_REPOSITORY_URL#*@}" "HEAD:main"
To https://gitlab.domain.com/project.git
  336b065..8299e43  HEAD -> main

$ git status
On branch main
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/main' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
```

Although everything the push is working on the release state `semantic-release` is still not working. I do get: `The local branch main is behind the remote one, therefore a new version won't be published.`

Comment: "after the push command I still have the detached head" - your updated output doesn't show that, it shows "on branch main". It shows you as "ahead of origin/main by 1 commit", but that's a different issue (it's probably because you pushed to an explicit URL rather than the "origin" remote)

Comment: @IMSoP So I should set the remote origin instead of using the repo url?

Comment: The message is just informational. It is not saying that you are on a detached head, or that the push failed. It's just comparing the current branch with the local cache of "origin/main". Pushing to "origin" rather than the URL would probably update that cache, as would running `git fetch origin`, but to re-emphasise *nothing has failed*.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46472250/cannot-push-from-gitlab-ci-yml https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51716044/how-do-i-push-to-a-repo-from-within-a-gitlab-ci-pipeline https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40122780/push-files-to-gitlab-ci-via-ci-runner  as for `I think the pipeline creates a detached repository by initial fetching` see https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/configure_runners.html#git-strategy

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I do not understand why the first `git status` in the before_script already gives me a detached head.
>
> I think the pipeline creates a detached repository by initial fetching.

You are right, GitLab CI does checkout a specific commit as opposed to a certain branch. You could however add `git checkout "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"` to your `before_script`:

```yaml
before_script:
  - git config --global user.name "Bot"
  - git config --global user.email "ci@domain.com"
  - git checkout "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
  - git status
```

Comment: I tried that just a few seconds before your answer. I've updated the post.

Answer (score 5):

I spend a lot of time to try to resolve the same problem and finally I found that there are git strategy: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/configure_runners.html#git-strategy

When there is set `fetch` then it re-uses the local working copy (and falls back to clone if it doesn’t exist). So this is the reason why it worked me for the first time and then it stopped working and my checkouted branch was behind and number of commits ahead increased with another commit.

Then the solution is pretty easy. You just need to define the `GIT_STRATEGY` variable to `clone`.

```yaml
variables:
  GIT_STRATEGY: clone
```

And my working `publish` job example:

```yaml
publish:
  stage: publish
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"
      when: manual
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: clone
  script:
    - git checkout -b $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
    - echo "define what you want to change"
    - 'git commit -am "your commit message" || echo "No changes to commit"'
    - git push --set-upstream origin $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
```

You can also define `clone` strategy in global variables or pipeline configuration https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/settings.html#choose-the-default-git-strategy.

Comment: `git checkout -b` creates a new branch, why did you need the `-b` flag?

Comment: The advantage of using `git checkout -b` is that it ensures you stay on the same commit - so if the server branch has moved on, this should be detected when you try to push. Otherwise, if you did `git checkout $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH` and it had moved on, your local code would no longer represent the commit you thought it was running on, but the new commit at the head of $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH

Answer (score 0):

This might help someone. Based on gitlab.

> The detached state is actually intended, as the runner is specifically
> designed to checkout the repository using a specific commit (the one
> that triggered the pipeline). When a specific commit is checked out,
> the repository is then considered to be in a "detached HEAD" state.

Here is an example from my pipeline that after changing some files, it pushes them to master (change master to main in new repos).

```
git remote set-url origin http://$user:$token@gitlab.com/<group>/<group>/$service.git
git add <file that changed>
git config --global user.email "<user email>"
git config --global user.name "<user name>"
git commit -m "Updated service $service"
git push -o ci.skip origin HEAD:master
```

`-o ci.skip` - is to stop running another pipeline after push to repo.

In gitlab you can do below to select the default branch from gitlab variables:

`git push -o ci.skip origin HEAD:$CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH`

To show all variables add `CI_DEBUG_TRACE: "true"` to variables section.